# Unable to use QFileSystemModel along custom QSortFilterProxy

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyqt, qt4.8

I'm new to qt and trying to hide some directories in a `QTreeView`. I'm trying to hide some folders based on their names using a custom `QSortFilterProxy` named `CacheFilterProxy`.

I setup the tree view this way:

```
fileModel = QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
rootIndex = fileModel.setRootPath(rootDir)
fileModel.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.Dirs | QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot)
fileModel.setNameFilters([patternString])
model = CacheFilterProxy()
model.setSourceModel(fileModel)
self.fileTreeView.setModel(model)
self.fileTreeView.setRootIndex(model.mapFromSource(rootIndex))
self.fileTreeView.clicked.connect(self.selectedFileChanged)
```

and then, in `self.selectedFileChanged` I try to extract fileName and filePath of currently selected item in tree view. Name of the file will be easily retrieved, but retrieving file path causes the whole program to stop working and then quit.

```
def selectedFileChanged(self, index):
    fileModel = self.fileTreeView.model().sourceModel()
    indexItem = self.fileTreeView.model().index(index.row(), 0, index.parent())
    # this works normal
    fileName = fileModel.fileName(indexItem)
    # this breaks the entire program
    filePath = fileModel.filePath(indexItem)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems wrong. Your `fileModel`is the source but I think `index` is a proxy index. I think you must map it to the source model before using it in the `fileModel`.

```
def selectedFileChanged(self, proxyIndex):
    sourceModel = self.fileTreeView.model().sourceModel()
    sourceIndex = self.fileTreeView.model().mapToSource(proxyIndex)
    sourceIndexCol0 = sourceModel.index(sourceIndex.row(), 0, sourceIndex.parent())

    # this works normal
    fileName = sourceModel.fileName(sourceIndexCol0)
    # this breaks the entire program
    filePath = sourceModel.filePath(sourceIndexCol0)
```

Note that I renamed `indexItem` to `sourceIndexCol0` as it is an index and not an item. It was a bit confusing at first glance.

I could not test the code above. If it doesn't work, verify that the indexes are valid before using them and check their model class.

Comment: Well, it seemed pretty obvious, and I already thought that I did it (cause I did the same in filter method) but some how I forgot to do it. And it is surprising that retrieving file name worked before.